# why is sqlite plugin not working with cordova app on ios

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova

I am building a cordova app for android and iOS that stores user information in a local database. However, I am unable to open a database connection on iOS.

The app works perfectly on android, but when I run it on iOS I get an error saying that window.sqlite is undefined. I have been searching the internet, but I can't find a related issue. I am not sure if my code has been setup incorrectly, or if I am missing some configuration for iOS. The SQLite plugin I am using "cordova-sqlite-evplus-legacy-free 0.9.1", and the cordova iOS version is "5.0.1".

```
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
            name: 'test.db',
            location: 'default',
            //iosDatabaseLocation: 'Library'
        },
        function(db) {
            if (clean_database) dumpDatabase();
            else buildSchemaVersions();
        },
        function(error) {
            db_error = error;
            alert('Open database ERROR: ' + error.message);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I would strongly advise against using a plugin for which the last update has been made more than 2 years ago, especially if it is for something as important as the database of your app. It is very likely that it has not been properly tested on current version of iOS. Why not use the more active plugin [`cordova-sqlite-storage`](https://github.com/xpbrew/cordova-sqlite-storage)? I have been using this plugin for years now without any issues whatsoever (iOS and Android).

For the question itself:

1. Did you make sure to make the `openDatabase` call *after* the `deviceready` event?
2. Was the plugin correctly added to the iOS platform? Please try removing it and adding it again and look out for any errors when it is added to the iOS platform.